# Is it safe to concurrently modify entries of a HashMap... IF the size of the map is fixed and the entries are linked lists?

Tags: java, concurrency, linked-list, hashmap

I currently have a fixed-size HashMap of linked lists, and I was wondering whether it would be safe to modify the values of two DIFFERENT keys by calling get() and then modifying the contents of that linked list (adding/subtracting nodes and stuff)? I know it's not safe to modify different keys at the same time due to possible resizing issues, but 1) the size of the hashmap is fixed and the linked lists are all initialized from the beginning (as empty lists) and 2) I suspect in a case like this the HashMap would store pointers to the linked lists thus modifying a list wouldn't actually modify the contents of the HashMap, but I can't be sure.

Anybody more familiar with Java able to answer this? And the reason I'm not using a thread-safe data structure to begin with is because it's forbidden by my project specs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should be fine since the map is effectively read-only. You might want to enforce this from the time it's initialized by using [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29) or Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html).

The linked lists are a different matter though, unless you can guarantee single-thread access to each individual list. If not, a quick solution would be wrapping each list using [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) at creation time. Or you could look at using [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)s instead.

Answer (score 1):

> And the reason I'm not using a thread-safe data structure to begin with is because it's forbidden by my project specs.

Ermm ... what they want you to do is implement your own synchronization using Java's lower level synchronization primitives.

That's not the same as doing unsynchronized operations on unsynchronized data structures.

---

For the record:

- If you are reading / updating the lists, that requires synchronization.
- Even an "effectively immutable" data structure needs to be published safely to avoid potential memory hazards.
- If you create a data structure in one thread and attempt to use it in another thread, there is a potential problem ... unless there is a happens-before relationship between the "create" and "use" actions.  (If the parent thread creates / initializes the data structure before calling `start()` on the child thread, that is sufficient ...)

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to modify any data, even a single boolean field concurrently without synchronization. The golden rule from "Java Concurrency in Practice": *Whenever more than one thread accesses a given state variable, and one of them might write to it, they all must coordinate their access to it using synchronization.*